# No recognizer is installed

Tags: vb.net, vb

he estado desarrollando un programa de reconocimiento de voz en visual basic .net 2019 con .net framework 5.0. AL parecer no tengo instalado el reconocedor de voz pero no estoy muy seguro de que debo hacer, no se donde puedo instalarlo o si tengo mas errores

Este es el error que me aparece:
[image: Esta es la imagen del error]

El codigo del programa es el siguiente:

```
Imports System.Speech
Imports SpeechLib
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Public Class Form3
Dim speech As SpVoice = New SpVoice()
Dim WithEvents Rec As New Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine
Dim synth As New Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 Try
Dim Gramatica As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsDocument
Dim Regla As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("Hola")
Dim Lista As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf("Hola", "Mucho gusto")
Dim Prueba As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-SP")
Regla.Add(Lista)
Gramatica.Rules.Add(Regla)
Gramatica.Root = Regla
Rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
Rec.LoadGrammar(New Recognition.Grammar(Gramatica))
Rec.RecognizeAsync()
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Reco_Recognized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognitionEventArgs) Handles Rec.SpeechRecognized
Select Case e.Result.Text
Case "Hola"
speech.Speak("Hola", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync)
Case Else
speech.Rate = 0
speech.Volume = 80
speech.Speak("No le entendi señor", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync)
End Select
 End Sub
Private Sub Reco_RecognizeCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizeCompletedEventArgs) Handles Rec.RecognizeCompleted
Rec.RecognizeAsync()
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Rec.Dispose()
synth.Dispose()
End Sub
End Class
```

Espero puedan ayudarme lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: que linea tira ese error? que dice la documentacion de las clases sobre ese error?

Comment: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'No recognizer is installed.'
Me lo tira en esta linea Rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()